# Load file if not exists in path

Tags: .htaccess

I want create css minify for WordPress. Minifed files will be save in wp-content/cache and width .min.css - example: wp-content/cache/themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css

I want change style url from:
www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css 
to
www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css

But I don't know how write htaccess rule. Htaccess Rule should be check if that file wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css exists. If file exists then file is load but if not exists then load file from wp-content/**cache**/*themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css*

My code:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^.*\.min.css$ /www-content/cache/$1.min.css [L]
```

This don't work

Comment: the code you have shown redirects nonexistent files (-f) and nonexistent directories/folders (-d) to the destination -- in your case, a .css file... you are misconceiving how .htaccess works

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
# if current file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# check presence of min.css in cache dir
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/cache/$2 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content)/(themes/[^/]+/.+?\.min.css)$ /$1/cache/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser?

Comment: hmm, no. in browser go to www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css if file exists in location wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css then load this file. If not exists then check if exists in wp-content/**cache**/themes/twentyfifteen/ and load this file

Comment: But you wrote: `www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css` which has no `min` after `style.`

Comment: Use update rule as very first rule just below `RewriteBase` line.

Answer (score 1):

this is NOT an .htaccess issue...

.htaccess would make all kinds of redirects for you based on the file you REQUESTED, but until you get the request into your WordPress flow, it will never request it...

since you are using WordPress, this will work (i tested it on my WordPress installation):

```
function load_minify() {
    foreach( array( 'wp-content', 'wp-content/cache' ) as $dir )
    {
        $fpath = $dir . '/themes/twentyfifteen/style.min.css';
        $froot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        if ( is_file( $froot . '/' . $fpath ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' . $fpath; ?>" />
    <?php
        break;
        endif;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'load_minify' );
```

add this anywhere in your parent or child `functions.php` file

**EDITED** to check theme folder first

Comment: is problem if in style.min.css will be background: url(../images/test.jpg);

Comment: the path to other resources from a stylesheet are relative to the stylesheet itself. so yes, if there is a relative URL to an image, and the image is not replicated in the cache, it will be broken. but if the stylesheet defines an absolute image URL, it won't be broken. which is why i never use relative URLs in stylesheets, javascripts, etc. but the OP's question is how to include a stylesheet file from either the them or the cache.

Comment: yes, this is problem. so my idea is use same url to css and change filename from style.css to style.min.css and use htaccess to check and load file

Comment: ok, that works then -- use the code above to get the request into the loop then use .htaccess to redirect to broken URLs requested by the stylesheet. .htaccess cannot help you without a `request` -- you have to be able to initiate the request somehow. (if you haven't figured it out by the nest time i check here, i will provide more details. i have to go now though)